# Shedule Push Notification using gcm and php to 80k and above users

Tags: php, cron, google-cloud-messaging

First i check the database table for finding the unsent message that has been posted by different users. and if it available then do the following code and run it using cron job every 5 min.

```
SELECT * FROM `jkeio_community_gcmusers`; //contain all gcm users
$i=0;

while($data_apps=mysql_fetch_array($data_app))
         {
 $message1=$i.'You have a new item in Akhbar';
 sendnotificationandroid($data_apps['gcm_regid'],$message1); //send function for sending push notification for android and it sends message via curl method
$i++;

             }
```

After sending the message I’ll set the unsent flag to sent using update query

All thing is OK in concern with 100 or 200 users but when users increase then messages are delivering on time that it should be
can you please suggest me how I can achieve that

Thanks in Advance
Anand Neema

Comment: Do NOT use mysql_* functions in your posted code since they are officially deprecated. As for your questions - I think curl_multi_* : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php - will do the stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCM allows us to send a notification to up to 1000 device at a time, so I suggest refactoring your method `sendnotificationandroid` to accept an array of gcm registration ids instead.

for example, you could first go through the database rows and collect the reg ids and append them to an array. Once the array size reaches 1000 (or no more reg ids to add), pass it to your new `sendnotificationandroid` method that will build the notification payload like this:

```
{
  "registration_ids" : ["regId1", "regId2", "regId3", ....., "regId1000"],
  "data" : {
    ...
  },
}
```

So, for 80K users, you will need about 80 loops to send the notifications, and as Alma Do Mundo suggested, it is better to use curl_multi_exec to send the requests to GCM server.